# Converting a map into another map using the java 8 stream API

Tags: dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Say I have the following map:

```
Map<Member, List<Message>> messages = ... //constructed somehow
```

I would like to use the java 8 stream api in order to obtain a:

```
SortedMap<Message, Member> latestMessages = ...
```

Where the comparator passed into the SortedMap/TreeMap would be based on the message sendDate field.

Furthermore, of the list of sent messages, I would select the latest message which would become the key to the sorted map.

How can I achieve that?

**edit 1**:

```
Comparator<Message> bySendDate = Comparator.comparing(Message::getSendDate);
SortedMap<Message, Member> latestMessages = third.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().max(bySendDate).get(), Map.Entry::getKey, (x, y) -> {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }, () -> new TreeMap(bySendDate.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Message::getId)))));
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
The method collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>) in the type Stream<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Map.Entry<Member,List<Message>>,?,TreeMap>)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want this? That will imply that there can be only one `Message` with a specific `sendDate`, even if different message with the same date but different sender and receiver exist.

Comment: Yes. Basically I will have the latest message sent to or from a given member.

Comment: I am actually implementing a message box such as the one on what'sapp or hangout, etc...

Comment: Oh, I am with you now! You're right. Let me edit my question....

Comment: @Holger I think it's the same question as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810301/issue-with-advanced-java-8-stream-usage I've come up with something; but maybe you have a better implementation (the question was not clear to me at first). ;-)

Comment: Hi ZouZou. Actually this question is slightly different even though the reply you provided was very useful, I need a reply to this question too. :-)

Comment: @Holger: what collection do you suggest I use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let’s dissolve this into two parts.

First, transform `Map<Member, List<Message>> messages` into a `Map<Message, Member> latestMessages` by *reducing* the messages for a particular communication partner (`Member`) to the latest:

```
Map<Message, Member> latestMessages0 = messages.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getValue().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Message::getSendDate)).get(),
        Map.Entry::getKey));
```

Here, the resulting `map` isn’t sorted but each mapping will contain the latest message shared with that participant.

---

Second, if you want to have the resulting map sorted by sendDate, you have to add another secondary sort criteria to avoid losing `Messages` which happen to have the same date. Assuming that you have a `Long` ID that is unique, adding this ID as secondary sort criteria for messages with the same date would be sufficient:

```
Comparator<Message> bySendDate=Comparator.comparing(Message::getSendDate);
SortedMap<Message, Member> latestMessages = messages.entrySet().stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
       e -> e.getValue().stream().max(bySendDate).get(),
       Map.Entry::getKey, (x,y) -> {throw new AssertionError();},
       ()->new TreeMap<>(bySendDate.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Message::getId)))));
```

Since sorting by the unique IDs should solve any ambiguity, I provided a merge function which will unconditionally throw, as calling it should never be required.

Comment: Thanks very much. However I am running into the above error... I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Note that `new TreeMap(…)` should be `new TreeMap<>(…)`, I forgot this `<>` thing but my compiler produces a warning only (and only with `-Xlint`) but maybe your compiler is more picky…

Comment: Exactly what I needed today ;-)